# Amazon s3 image scaling

Tags: channel-images, s3, devdemon, resize, amazon

i'd like to use devdemon channel images on amazon s3 hosts but i need to dynamically resizing images on http requests.

i need something very similar to the google cdn:

for example, adding the =s paramter to scale the image i get the needed image

http://lh6.ggpht.com/VMLEHAa3kSHEoRr7AchhQ6HEzHVTn1b7Mf-whpxmPlpdrRfPW216UhYdQy3pzIe4f8Q7PKXN79AD4eRqu1obC7I=s200

do you know if there's similar options on amazon s3? i've looked inside docs, support sites and forums but i was not lucky, too much informations and nothing clear for me (i'm not a expert developer).

or there's a way to use channel images with google cdn in a simply way like as s3?

please, if you know how to do it let me know, thank you
Valerio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [**CE Image**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-image).

- Can implement dynamic resizing based on request (use segment variables or GET variables for the dimension parameters on the CE Image template tag).
- Will save manipulated images to Amazon S3.
- Can be used in conjunction with Channel Images (just don't bother with the Channel Image's resizing feature and rely completely on CE Image for that).

Comment: Dear Alex, unfortunately I haven't solve my problem yet. My goal would be do this: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/19157/2590