# Storing images entries on Google Drive or Amazon S3

Tags: image, channel-images, ce-image, image-path

sorry again for my bad english..

I'd like to use Amazon S3 or Google Drive as CDN for my images posts. I have a script that adds dynamic parameters at the end of the url image.

So if i have an image like:

```
<img src="http://mysite.it/images/image.jpg" alt="{title}">
```

my script automatically returns:

```
<img src="http://mysite.it/images/image.jpg&s=1200" alt="{title}">
```

Google drive do a fantastic scaling images on the fly *(try to change the number at the end of the image)*:

http://lh6.ggpht.com/VMLEHAa3kSHEoRr7AchhQ6HEzHVTn1b7Mf-whpxmPlpdrRfPW216UhYdQy3pzIe4f8Q7PKXN79AD4eRqu1obC7I=s200

or

http://lh6.ggpht.com/VMLEHAa3kSHEoRr7AchhQ6HEzHVTn1b7Mf-whpxmPlpdrRfPW216UhYdQy3pzIe4f8Q7PKXN79AD4eRqu1obC7I=s500

So... how can i upload images from CP to google drive? I have purchased channel images by devdemon and CE Image but they do it only on Amazon S3.

There's a way to use Amazon S3 with url parameters for scaling images?

please, someone let me know if I can do it
thank you!
Valerio

Comment: from my point of view, is not really good way to choose Google Drive for image hosting, because Google is not such company who can keep they policy unchangeable. Today is open, tomorrow they will closed it  or limited by showing. Better to choose s3 and just scale it using ce_image.  If you think about how to scale inline images (in text), you can read about exp:ce_img:bulk.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it would be possible to do this, but you probably need to write quite a large extension to channel images to make it possible.

What's your skill level?

Comment: unfortunately i'm not a developer.. :(

Comment: I'm sorry to say that there doesn't appear to be a ready-made extension that will use google drive as a cdn. I suspect you may have some challenges doing that anyway, as strictly speaking, google drive isn't intended to be a cdn.

Comment: I understand.. anyway i'm looking for a way to do the same thing on Amazon S3. There must be an API that works with url parameters.. (i hope so!)

Comment: s3 don't have internal tools for image scale. It is just a storage.

Comment: You can resize the image on upload, so the correct size is uploaded to s3, would that be sufficient?

Comment: no because i need to resize images on the fly each time a user request the page in order to fit the images to the browser window.. :)

Comment: That doesn't sound wonderful.  Can you not do something with image scaling and media queries to do this?  Otherwise, you'll be deferring a lot of load to dynamically create images on each request, leading to a slow loading page; Rather than using the benefits of a CDN: fast, smartly cached requests, leading to fast pages.